# Need a small advice on the DB query optimization

Tags: django, django-orm

Question is about code optimization, to be exact -DB query optimization:

```py
…
…
…

filter1 = Comment.objects.filter(foreignkey_to_model1__author=self.request.user,
                                 is_active=True)
filter2 = Comment.objects.filter(foreignkey_to_model2__author=self.request.user,
                                 is_active=True)
context["comments_by_user"] = filter1.union(filter2)[: 5]
return context
```

I feel like this code is suck as it consist of the 2 queries + slice instead of filter on a DB level. 
Question – is it any chance to pack it in 1 query nicely  in order to decrease load on the DB? ( and make this code less suck…)
Thanks

Comment: This *is* doing a single query. Neither of the filter1 or filter2 are actually evaluated independently, and the slice is translated into a db LIMIT call. However, it's true it would be better to have a single OR rather than a UNOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

filter = Comment.objects.filter(
    Q(foreignkey_to_model1__author=self.request.user) | 
    Q(foreignkey_to_model2__author=self.request.user),
    is_active=True
)[:5]
```